# A faster way to do simultaneous asynchronous requests in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, callback, request

So far this has been my method of making two dependent requests

```
https.get(url, (response) => {
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body+=chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', () => {
        var firstData = JSON.parse(body);

        body = "";
        url = somethingNew.com;

        https.get(url, (response) => {
            response.on('data', (chunk) => {
                body+=chunk;
            });
            response.on('end', (chunk) => {
                var secData = JSON.parse(body);
                return firstData.someResource + secData.someResource;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I have heard of using callbacks in these situations, but are they faster/more efficient? Or are they just a cleaner way to do what I have been doing above?

Comment: You are using callbacks.  And your requests are not simultaneous.  What is your question?

Comment: Hmmm, then I'm having trouble wording it. Should these requests be in the format above? Or should I call a seperate function at the end of the first request that makes the second request?

Comment: I guess the question is: Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: Whether your function is directly a callback or a separate function makes no difference.  However, learn about promises, which are much nicer.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you!